# For loop - how to?

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I am trying to run the following code in Android but there seems to be some problem with the for loop. The code builds without any build error but when I try access the second element of the array station_id it gives a runtime error. If I try to access station_id[0], then there is no error at all. I was not sure if the for loop actually loops over and stores the data in every element of the array. Therefore I tried printing the value of i to check if the for loop runs 187 times. However, 'i' is printed only once in the logcat of Android studio. I could not figure out where it goes wrong. Your suggestions would be of great help. Below is my code.

```
public class LoadDataOnce {
    private String Url_get_data;
    private String result_fullData;
    private JSONArray fullData;
    // GetData - class that sends http get request and fetches data
    private GetData getfullData;
    private String [] station_id;
    private String []  station_coordinates;
    private int total_num_of_stations;

public LoadDataOnce() {
    Url_get_data = "http://fluggs.wupperverband.de/sos2/api/v1/timeseries/";
    result_fullData = null;
    fullData = null;
    getfullData = new GetData();
    station_id = new String[187];
    station_coordinates = new String[187];
    total_num_of_stations = 0;
}


public String[] getStation_id() {

    return station_id;

}



public String [] getStation_coordinates() {
    return station_coordinates;
}



public int getTotal_num_of_stations() {
    return total_num_of_stations;
}




public void loadData () {

    try {
        result_fullData = getfullData.execute(Url_get_data).get();

        try {
            fullData = new JSONArray(result_fullData);
            total_num_of_stations = fullData.length();
            //station_id =  new String [total_num_of_stations];
            station_coordinates = new String[total_num_of_stations];
            for (int i = 0; i < 187; i++){
                station_id[i] = fullData.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("station").getJSONObject("properties").getString("id");
                System.out.println(i);
                station_coordinates[i] = fullData.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("geometry").getString("coordinates");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


}
```

Exception that I get while testing in Android 7.0 phone.

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
    ComponentInfo{com.example.charu.droidar_wupperverband/system.ArActivity}: 
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
    at 
    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2924)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at 

  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:969)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:948)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:915)
    at util.IO.loadBitmapFromView(IO.java:158)
    at util.IO.loadBitmapFromView(IO.java:140)
    at gl.GLFactory.newTextObject(GLFactory.java:611)
    at com.example.charu.droidar_wupperverband.WupperAugment._b_addWorldsToRenderer(WupperAugment.java:106)
    at system.Setup.run(Setup.java:254)
    at system.ArActivity.runSetup(ArActivity.java:61)
    at system.ArActivity.onCreate(ArActivity.java:38)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6912)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2877)
    ... 9 more


 <Debug Infos>
 OS Version: 3.18.14-12365438 (G930FXXU1DQJ8)
 OS API Level: 24
 Device: herolte
 Model (and Product): SM-G930F (heroltexx)
 Manufacturer: samsung
 Other TAGS: release-keys
 screenWidth: 1080
 screenHeigth: 1920
 Keyboard available: false
 Trackball available: false
 SD Card state: mounted
```

Comment: What exception do you get.

Comment: Show us what exception do you see

Answer (score 0):

maybe JSON return null value or is not a valid definition:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 187; i++){
            String s1=fullData.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("station").getJSONObject("properties").getString("id");
            if(s1!=null)
                 station_id[i] =s1 
            System.out.println(i);

            String s2= fullData.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("geometry").getString("coordinates");
            if(s2!=null)
                station_coordinates[i] =s2
        }
```

Comment: Hey..thanks but it did not work..and I am pretty sure that the second element of the JSON object is not null and not sure why even the print statement does not run as expected.

Comment: It will get an error, so program pointer goes to catch so 'i' will not increase in the next count. But I think the problem is somewhere else. where did you use 'loadData ()' ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem is..

"the third statement of the for loop has turned out to be wrong"!! and hence the loop has been broken the very first time and did not run for the rest of the times. The error is that the data fetched and the format in which I tried to store it has been different..The request returns an array which I tried storing in a String.  Sorry for the inconvenience.